# copy value of jquery UI auto-complete in select function to a textfield?

Tags: javascript, php

I created this javascript wherein it will create a row of textfield for multiple insertion purposes.. My problem is I'd like to add an auto complete wherein it will query the data inserted on the text field from the database and fill its remaining data record on other textfield. It seems I having a problem in putting the data on the textfield since its id is incremented.

here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<form name="zxc" method="POST">  
<div id="sit" align="center"><label><input type="text" id="set" name="set" placeholder="Set number of rows..."></label>
<button type="button" id="cret" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" onClick="createinput();hide();autoComp();">Add rows</button></div>
<br>
```

**Javascript**

```
function autoComp(){
    $(function(){
        var id2=0;
        var num = parseInt(document.forms["zxc"]["set"].value);

        if(!num) return;

        for(var count=1;count<=num;count++, id2++){

            $("#unit"+id2).autocomplete({
                source:'search2.php',
                minLength:1,
                select:function(evt, ui) {      
                 this.form.description+id2.value = ui.item.description;
                 this.form.unit_value+id2.value = ui.item.unitValue;                    
                }
            });

        }
    });
}
```

**PHP**

```
include '../core/database/config.php';
$term= $_GET["term"];
$rs= mysql_query("SELECT unit,description,unitValue FROM csr_inventory where unit like '%".$term."%' order by unit");
$data = array();
if ( $rs && mysql_num_rows($rs) ) {
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($rs) )
    {
        $data[] = array(
        'value' => $row['unit'] ,
        'description' => $row['description'] ,
        'unitValue' => $row['unitValue']
        );
    }
}
echo json_encode($data);
flush();
```

please help me solving this problem... :(

Comment: Please don't use $_GET data directly in the code.
Also don't use mysql_query, this function is deprecated.

Comment: how can I increment description from this line `this.form.description.value` is there any other way?

Comment: @user2959418 he means you need to properly sanitize any data you pass to php and vice versa. you also need to stop using insecure mysql functions immediately. and by immediately i mean right this second, go learn mysqli or pdo. it takes about 10 minutes of trial and error if you already know mysql.